# PostgreSQL schemas and search_path

Tags: postgresql, schema

I'm reading Oreilly's *PostgreSQL: Up and Running*, and in the section *Organizing Your Database Using Schemas* it says the `search_path` may be set at the database level:

> For example, if we wanted all objects in contrib to be accessible without schema qualification, we would change our database as follows:
>
> `ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path="$user",public,contrib;`

However, after typing the command above, I still can't refer to tables in schemas other then `public` without qualifying them:

```
ALTER DATABASE auth SET search_path="$user",public,staging;`
\d users
```

Gives:

```
Did not find any relation named "users".
```

But if I use `\d staging.users`, it works.

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Gives:

```
   search_path   
----------------
 "$user",public
```

Does the default `search_path` from `postgresql.conf` override the per-database value set with `ALTER DATABASE ... SET search_path` ? If that's the case, what's the use of the per-database value?

Comment: can you `select * from users`?

Comment: No, I can't `select * from users` but I can `select * from staging.users`.

Comment: Did you reconnect to your database after setting a new default for its `search_path`? Did you try just setting the `search_path` for your connection?

Comment: I hadn't reconnected yet. Reconnecting psql solved my problem, thanks. Would you write an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Daniel, it's not a syntax error in MySQL (" vs '). Single and double quotes are treated the same (unless it's set on `ANSI` SQL mode). (Commenting here as you wouldn't see it there. I'll delete this comment later)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The citation from the `SET` related paragraph of the [`ALTER DATABASE` documentation section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) is "Whenever a new session is subsequently started in that database, the specified value becomes the session default value". So the changes will take effect for new sessions only. You just need to reconnect.

Comment: Without reconnecting, to modify search_path on the current session (in your psql session, for example) you can use `SET search_path TO "$user",public,contrib;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but worked when I altered the user/role with search_path:

```
demo=> ALTER ROLE bk_test_pg IN DATABASE demo SET search_path TO public, bookings;
ALTER ROLE

demo=> \dt
                List of relations
  Schema  |      Name       | Type  |   Owner    
----------+-----------------+-------+------------
 bookings | aircrafts_data  | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | airports_data   | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | boarding_passes | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | bookings        | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | flights         | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | seats           | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | ticket_flights  | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | tickets         | table | bk_test_pg
(8 rows)
```

Before I did for session only and in the new terminal I got same "did not find any relation" error.

```
demo=> SET search_path TO "$user", public, bookings;
SET
demo=> SHOW search_path;
        search_path        
---------------------------
 "$user", public, bookings
(1 row)

demo=> \dt
                List of relations
  Schema  |      Name       | Type  |   Owner    
----------+-----------------+-------+------------
 bookings | aircrafts_data  | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | airports_data   | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | boarding_passes | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | bookings        | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | flights         | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | seats           | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | ticket_flights  | table | bk_test_pg
 bookings | tickets         | table | bk_test_pg
(8 rows)
```

So merely altering the search_path with `SET search_path TO schema1, schema2, schema3;` will only remain in the session.